# PL/SQL Selecting "Monday Dates" of Year

Tags: date, plsql

I have this PL/SQL script

```
WITH
                date_range (mydate)
                AS
                    (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - 7, 'mm') - 1 + LEVEL
                           FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                  TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE - 7, 12), 'mm')
                                - TRUNC (SYSDATE - 7, 'mm')),
                weeknum_per_date (mydate, nr_of_sundays)
                AS
                    (SELECT mydate,
                                (  TRUNC (mydate, 'day')
                                 - TRUNC (TRUNC (mydate, 'yyyy'), 'day'))
                              / 7
                            + CASE
                                  WHEN TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'YYYY'),
                                                'day') =
                                       'sun'
                                  THEN
                                      1
                                  ELSE
                                      0
                              END    AS nr_of_sundays
                       FROM date_range)
              SELECT TO_CHAR (mydate, 'YYYY')    AS year,
                     LISTAGG (
                         DISTINCT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'MONTH'), 'MONTH'),
                         ', ')                   AS MONTHS,
                     (nr_of_sundays + 1)         week_num
                FROM weeknum_per_date
               WHERE TO_DATE (mydate, 'DD/MM/YY') >=
                     TO_DATE (SYSDATE - 7, 'DD/MM/YY')
            GROUP BY (nr_of_sundays + 1), TO_CHAR (mydate, 'YYYY')
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR (mydate, 'YYYY'),
                     TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm00');
```

This code returns the year, months of the current week, week number of the year

Without changing the working code, I want to add another column which shows the **dates of the Mondays of the year**.

the original script returns that:

**YEAR|    MONTHS|      WEEK_NUM**

2023|   APRIL|      15

2023|   APRIL|      16

2023|   APRIL|      17

2023|   APRIL    , MAY|         18

2023|   MAY|        19

.

.

.

(52 weeks)

I want it to return:
**YEAR|    MONTHS|      WEEK_NUM|    MONDAY_DATE_OF_THE_WEEK**

2023|   APRIL|      15|     17.04.2023

2023|   APRIL|      16|     24.04.2023

2023|   APRIL|      17|     01.05.2023

2023|   APRIL    , MAY|         18|     08.05.2023

2023|   MAY|        19|     15.05.2023

.

.

.

(52 weeks)

Can you guys help me how can I achieve that?

Thank you for your help.

Edit after @Paul W's answer and additional LEAD function, following script returns the desired output, there may be better and more optimal solution but this is the script returning the desired output:

```
WITH
                date_range (mydate)
                AS
                    (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - 7, 'mm') - 1 + LEVEL
                           FROM DUAL
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                  TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE - 7, 12), 'mm')
                                - TRUNC (SYSDATE - 7, 'mm')),
                weeknum_per_date (mydate, nr_of_sundays)
                AS
                    (SELECT mydate,
                                (  TRUNC (mydate, 'day')
                                 - TRUNC (TRUNC (mydate, 'yyyy'), 'day'))
                              / 7
                            + CASE
                                  WHEN TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'YYYY'),
                                                'day') =
                                       'sun'
                                  THEN
                                      1
                                  ELSE
                                      0
                              END    AS nr_of_sundays
                       FROM date_range)
              SELECT TO_CHAR (mydate, 'YYYY')    AS year,

                     LISTAGG (
                         DISTINCT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'MONTH'), 'MONTH'),
                         ', ')                   AS MONTHS,
                     (nr_of_sundays + 1)         week_num,
                     LEAD (TRUNC(MIN(mydate),'IW'),1,TRUNC(MIN(mydate+7),'IW')) OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(MIN(mydate),'IW')) AS MONDAY_DATE
                FROM weeknum_per_date
               WHERE TO_DATE (mydate, 'DD/MM/YY') >=
                     TO_DATE (SYSDATE - 7, 'DD/MM/YY')
            GROUP BY (nr_of_sundays + 1), TO_CHAR (mydate, 'YYYY')
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR (mydate, 'YYYY'),
                     TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your last query block:

```
TRUNC(MIN(mydate),'IW') monday
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working but there is a problem, it returns:

2023 APRIL     16 17/04/2023,

2023 APRIL     17 17/04/2023,

2023 APRIL    , MAY       18 24/05/2023,

it's duplicating 17/04/2023 , it should be

2023 APRIL     16 17/04/2023,

2023 APRIL     17 24/04/2023,

2023 APRIL    , MAY       18 01/05/2023,

can you help me how can I achieve that?